# Calculate ipv6 number in use in us?

Tags: ipv6

To calculate total ipv4 number in use in us.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.apnic.net/stats/arin/delegated-arin-extended-20170101
(cat delegated-arin-extended-20170101 | grep  -i 'US|ipv4' |cut -f 5 -d'|' | tr '\n' '+';echo 0) | bc
1608099840
```

It is a huge number `1608099840`.
How to calculate ipv6 number in use in us?

```
 (cat delegated-arin-extended-20170101 | grep  -i 'US|ipv6' |cut -f 5 -d'|' | tr '\n' '+';echo 0) | bc
179768
```

For ipv6 address in use in us as little as `179768` or it is a wrong method to calculate ?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the definition of "in use". Aren't these block assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPv4 delegations show the number of addresses in the delegation. IPv6 delegations show the prefix length of the delegation. If you want numbers then for each of the numbers take the length of an IPv6 address (128 bits) minus the prefix length, and calculate 2 to the power of that number to get the number of addresses in that prefix.

This should do it:

```
(cat delegated-arin-extended-20170101 | grep  -i 'US|ipv6' | cut -f 5 -d'|' | tr '\n' '+';
 echo 0) | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)/2^(128-\1)/g' | bc
```

Which gives you the more plausible number of `340285729632951762352437572028715761664`. However, that is the number of addresses delegated. It doesn't tell you much about how many are in use.